Await call doesn't wait for Completion second time onwards when called
I have a situation where we have to display a content view which is used as a popup control, it contains 2 fields and 2 buttons (Next and cancel). The requirement is to not close the popup till the user clicks either of the button.
The code uses async await operation to wait for the result, however only when the application is running for the first time, The code waits for the answer and after that anytime you open the popup other code also gets executed.
On debugging I observed that when the first call is made, the code  that returns the task has status "Waiting for Activation" while from the second time onwards it is "Ran for completion".
Any idea on why such behaviour and how can I stop the code for further execution till the buttons on the popups are clicked??

Please Note: The same code works with Xamarin forms while it is not working for MAUI.
Below are the code snippets.
UI calling code on some button click:
    private async Task CreateDelivery(Supplier selectedSupplier)
{
    var res = false;
    if(configData.EnableDeliveryIDEditpopup)
    {
        IsBusy = false;
        res = await _navigationService.GoToAddDeliveryPopupView(selectedSupplier);
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(selectedSupplier));
        if (!res)
            return;
    }            
    var delivery = new Delivery();
    delivery.deliveryDate = DateTime.Now;
    delivery.supplierId = selectedSupplier.SupplierId;
    delivery.supplierType = Convert.ToInt32(selectedSupplier.SupplierTypeId);
    delivery.deliveryId = selectedSupplier.DeliveryId;
    var result = await _deliveryNoteService.AddDeliveryAsync(delivery);
    if (result != null && result.deliveryNo != null)
        GoToDeliveryNote(result);
    else
    {
        var response = await BaseNavigationService.DisplayTwoOptionsPopup(
             new TwoOptionsPopupDto
             {
                 Title = "Error",
                 Text = result.message,                         
                 RightOptionText = "Ok"
             });
        if(response)
            await CreateDelivery(selectedSupplier);
    }
        
}

GoToAddDeliveryPopupView:
public async Task<bool> GoToAddDeliveryPopupView(Supplier SupplierName)
{
    var result = await _navigationService.DisplayPopup<AddDeliveryPopupViewModel, ConfirmationViewModel>(SupplierName);
    return await result.AgreedSource.Task; //This line is Waiting for Activation for first time and then RanForCOmpletion every other time
}

Display popup
public async Task<TOut> DisplayPopup<TViewModel, TOut>(object navigationData = null)
    where TViewModel : TOut where TOut : class
{
    try
    {
        using (await _asyncLock.LockAsync())
        {
            var popupPage = await _viewFactoryService.CreatePopupPage(typeof(TViewModel), navigationData);
            await _popupNavigation.PushAsync(popupPage);

            if (_deviceContext == null)
            {
                _deviceContext = DeviceContext.Instance;
            }

            _lastScannerState = _deviceContext.ScannerMgr.ScannerEnabled;
            _deviceContext.ScannerMgr.ScannerEnabled = false;

            if (popupPage.BindingContext is TOut returnValue)
                return returnValue;

            return popupPage.Content.BindingContext as TOut;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw;
    }
}

ConfirmationViewModel:
public class ConfirmationViewModel : ViewModelBase, IAnswer<bool>
{
    private readonly INavigationService _navigationService;
    public TaskCompletionSource<bool> AgreedSource = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    private bool _result;
    public ConfirmationViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;
    }
}   


According to your discription: after that anytime you open the popup other code also gets executed.  What function is running of other code? Can you provide the relevant code?

@ShuowenHe-MSFT: by other code i mean the next lines in the code block which has some database operations, so the popup stays on the screen as is , but the background screen automatically changes because the code has processed.
Also the value of the result is basically the first button, so in my case it considers cancel and moves forward.

Some more information that I think could be helpful, earlier when this was implemented in Xamarin forms, we were using .net 2.0 and with MAUI it is .net 8.0

I still cannot find the problem about your code; more information is needed: What navigation stack are you using? Where do you expect the code to wait that it isn't?

@ShuowenHe-MSFT: the below line that i have shared as code snippet, calls the popup. The subsequent method code also i have pasted.
res = await _navigationService.GoToAddDeliveryPopupView(selectedSupplier);
It is expected that when user wants to create a new record so app navigates from list page to new record page, before that we display this popup

the popup has a input field which is needed for creating the new record, however since the code doesnt wait for the user clicking the button, the code considers that no input was shared and thus navigates to next page calling the API to create the record.

@ShuowenHe-MSFT: it was a coding glitch, the line: public TaskCompletionSource AgreedSource = new TaskCompletionSource(); this variable was storing the previously selected value and thus everytime we click the new btn for the second time it was having the status as "RanForCompletion" and so the call was not awaited.
OnDisappearing I refreshed this variable and then it works.

You can post the solution as the answer, which would be helpful for others who have the similar problem.
